# Scalable solution for extracting semantic data from websites?

Tags: web-scraping, nlp, html-parsing, semantic-web

Let's say I have a (rather large) number of websites on my disk, scraped or fetched from e.g. Common Crawl. I have no prior knowledge about the HTML structure, assume that each page is structured differently (which is usually the case). From each of them I want to extract some kinds of semantic information (known in advance) like articles/posts with metadata (date, author, tags, comments, etc.).

One straightforward way to go would be to write a simple parser for each of the websites, given good quality parsing libraries out there it should be easy enough. But this approach obviously does not scale. Is there a more clever solution to this problem? How would I proceed and what is actually the difficulty of this task?

You can include paid services, if anything like this exists. If you're aware of any better way of getting this kind of data (on a specific topic; instead of manual scraping / Common Crawl) please also include it.

Comment: [This question is not suited to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). That said, [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces a tool you may want to try -- the [Virtuoso Sponger](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSponger) -- which you can see in action at [URIBurner](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/).

Comment: https://github.com/ldspider/ldspider has RDFa extractor